# Angular-Ionic $interval is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm using $interval for repeat every 10 seconds a function but when the app is runnning it return me "Type error: $interval is not a function".

this is the code:

```
app.controller("ctrl2", ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth", "HitService", 
"$location", "$ionicPopup", "sharedList", "$ionicLoading", "$ionicLoading",  "$interval",
    function ($scope, firebaseAuth, HitService, $location, $ionicPopup, sharedList, ionicLoading, $interval) {

function aggiornaToken() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    console.log(user);
    var token = user.refreshToken;
    console.log(token);
    //HitService.setToken(token); 
}
$interval(aggiornaToken, 10000);
```

Comment: You injected $ionicLoading twice...

Comment: Damn! I am very distracted lately :/ thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a problem about [dependency injections](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

You can see that the **ordering is important with Angular injections.**

The only time ordering is not relevant, is when you use implicit injections, which is generally a bad practice because you can't minify, and it makes your code less clear and less scalable.

Also, you should start to use $inject instead of using the inline array annotation. Both works, but Angular guidelines generally ask to use $inject.

```
app.controller("ctrl2", ctrl2Function);

ctrl2Function.$inject = ["$scope", "$firebaseAuth", "HitService", "$location", "$ionicPopup", "sharedList", "$ionicLoading", "$interval"];

function ctrl2Function ($scope, firebaseAuth, HitService, $location, $ionicPopup, 
sharedList, ionicLoading, $interval) {
}
```

(Notice that you injected twice ionicLoading and I removed that).